# is it possible to add a custom constraint in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Now I have a table store some rss subscribe url, sometimes the url end with '/', now I replace all url without end with '/'. to make sure the sub url did not end with '/'. I want to add a custom constraint in the rss sub source table. If the sub url end with '/', throw error to the app. I have read the PostgreSQL 13 [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/ddl-constraints.html), and found it have many constraint like uniq constraint check constraint with the int data type. but how to add an constraint with a string data type and make sure the string did not end with '/'? is there any way to do this action?

Comment: That would be a [check constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS) I believe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD CONSTRAINT c
    CHECK ( url NOT LIKE '%/');
```

As suggested by [Vérace](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/34007/v%C3%A9race) in comment, an alternative would be a generated column as:

```
ALTER TABLE T ADD COLUMN proper_url TEXT 
    GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( regexp_replace(url, '/$', '')) STORED;
```

Comment: Or a generated/computed column - accept either and store it "pure" in the computed column (virtual?). PostgreSQL doesn't have virtual ones yet though. Just a thought - I know the OP wants a constraint, but strings with a `/` at the end will throw an error - this way, they won't!

Comment: @verace, I added your comment in my answer

Comment: And I upvoted your answer, it obviously having become erudite and distinguished! :-)